# Control the number of rectangles drawn on canvas to 4

Tags: javascript, loops, canvas

[image: Checkerboard**enter code here**]
I got this code that draws rectangles on a canvas. I need code to check the loop and make sure the number of rectangles(x wise) drawn on the canvas is equal to 4. It's a checkerboard game am trying to create. Your help is greatly appreciated. Here is the code so far

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<canvas>
</canvas>
</body>
<script>
     const canvas = document.querySelector('canvas')
     canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
     canvas.height = window.innerHeight;

     //create a two dimensional context
     const c = canvas.getContext('2d')
     //make a teal colored rectangle
     c.fillStyle = '#ccc'
     c.fillRect(0, 0, 100, 100)
     //make a pink rectangle
     c.fillStyle = '#fff'
     c.fillRect(100, 100, 100, 100)
     //create rectangle object
     function Rectangle(x, y, width, height, color) {
       this.x = x
       this.y = y
       this.width = width
       this.height = height
       this.color = color
       this.draw = function() {
         c.fillStyle = this.color
         c.fillRect(this.x, this.y, this.width, this.height)
       }
     }
     // Make grey rectangles at 200 px intervals
     for (let i = 0; i < canvas.width; i += 200) {
       for (let j = 0; j < canvas.height; j += 200) {
         let rectangle = new Rectangle(i, j, 100, 100, 'rgba(128,128,128,1.0)')
         rectangle.draw()
         c.beginPath();
         c.fillStyle = '#404040';
         c.arc(i + 50, j + 50, 25, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
         c.fill();
         c.closePath();
       }
     }
     // Make grey rectangles at 200 px intervals
     for (let i = 100; i < canvas.width; i += 200) {
       for (let j = 100; j < canvas.height; j += 200) {
         let rectangle = new Rectangle(i, j, 100, 100, 'rgba(128,128,128,1)');
         rectangle.draw();
         c.beginPath();
         c.fillStyle = '#404040';
         c.arc(i + 50, j + 50, 25, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
         c.fill();
         c.closePath();
       }
     }

</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Parameterize by the number of rectangles, rather than pixels. Also, it makes sense to run the loop once, and build an odd-even condition to determine color.

```js
const canvas = document.querySelector('canvas')
const c = canvas.getContext('2d')
//make a teal colored rectangle
c.fillStyle = '#ccc'
c.fillRect(0, 0, 100, 100)
//make a pink rectangle
c.fillStyle = '#fff'
c.fillRect(100, 100, 100, 100)
//create rectangle object
function Rectangle(x, y, width, height, color) {
  this.x = x
  this.y = y
  this.width = width
  this.height = height
  this.color = color
  this.draw = function() {
    c.fillStyle = this.color
    c.fillRect(this.x, this.y, this.width, this.height)
  }
}

 const squarePx = 100
 // const cols = 4, rows = Math.ceil(canvas.height / squarePx)
 const cols = 8, rows = 8
 for (let col = 0; col < cols; col++) {
   for (let row = 0; row < rows; row++) {
     let x = col * squarePx, y = row * squarePx
     // on even rows, even cols are dark. on odd rows, odd cols are dark
     let evenRow = row % 2 === 0, evenCol = col % 2 === 0
     let fillStyle = evenRow === evenCol ? '#222' : '#888' 
     // draw at x, y, using fillStyle
     let rectangle = new Rectangle(x, y, squarePx, squarePx, fillStyle)
     rectangle.draw()
   }
 }
```

```html
<html>
  <head></head>
<body>
  <canvas width='800' height='800'></canvas>
</body>
```

Comment: You didn't close the braces of your loop, fiddle is throwing an error

Comment: @CodeTiger, As is customary, in order to highlight the pertinent part, my answer also omitted all of the tags and drawing code that you had built correctly.  In the edit, I added two closing braces and demonstrated in the snippet editor.

Comment: Am going to test it on fiddle, can you further edit it to make it limit to 8 in the x and 8 in the y

Comment: @CodeTiger, I left the original line that determines row and col count commented in place, for your future reference. Replaced it with `rows = 8, cols = 8`

Comment: One more favor actually brother?

Comment: Thanks for the answer and your code, how can i draw player one red circles and player 2  white circles on the boxes

Comment: @CodeTiger - answered in your other question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66723945/how-do-i-draw-circles-on-a-checker-boards-squares-to-make-it-look-like-a-real-c/66724549#66724549

Comment: Okay thanks, i tested it let me see how i can modify it to draw on every square i need, thanks in advance and God bless you

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use a counter as follows:-

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<canvas>
</canvas>
</body>
<script>
     const canvas = document.querySelector('canvas')
     canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
     canvas.height = window.innerHeight;

     //create a two dimensional context
     const c = canvas.getContext('2d')
     //make a teal colored rectangle
     c.fillStyle = '#ccc'
     c.fillRect(0, 0, 100, 100)
     //make a pink rectangle
     c.fillStyle = '#fff'
     c.fillRect(100, 100, 100, 100)
     //create rectangle object
     function Rectangle(x, y, width, height, color) {
       this.x = x
       this.y = y
       this.width = width
       this.height = height
       this.color = color
       this.draw = function() {
         c.fillStyle = this.color
         c.fillRect(this.x, this.y, this.width, this.height)
       }
     }
     let count = 0
     // Make grey rectangles at 200 px intervals
     for (let i = 0; (i < canvas.width && count<=10); i += 200) {
       for (let j = 0; j < canvas.height; j += 200) {
         let rectangle = new Rectangle(i, j, 100, 100, 'rgba(128,128,128,1.0)')
         rectangle.draw()
         c.beginPath();
         c.fillStyle = '#404040';
         c.arc(i + 50, j + 50, 25, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
         c.fill();
         c.closePath();
         count++;
       }
     }
     count = 0
     // Make grey rectangles at 200 px intervals
     for (let i = 100; (i < canvas.width && count<=10); i += 200) {
       for (let j = 100; j < canvas.height; j += 200) {
         let rectangle = new Rectangle(i, j, 100, 100, 'rgba(128,128,128,1)');
         rectangle.draw();
         c.beginPath();
         c.fillStyle = '#404040';
         c.arc(i + 50, j + 50, 25, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
         c.fill();
         c.closePath();
         count++;
       }
     }

</script>
```

Comment: Works but doesn' t control the number of rectangles x-wise

Comment: Am getting the desired output x-wise but y-wise, the rectangles are two, check your code at jsfiddle