# How do I draw circles on a checker-board's squares to make it look like a real checker-board?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I have managed to draw a checker-board with JavaScript and canvas. The problem I have now is making sure my code gives output like the real checker picture here:

[image]

What can I do with my JavaSCript code to make it draw the circles on the rectangles to produce output like that of a real checker piece?

Player one circles should be red, player two circles should be black.

Here is the code for my checkers file:

```js
const canvas = document.querySelector('canvas')
canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
canvas.height = window.innerHeight;

//create a two dimensional context
const c = canvas.getContext('2d')
//make a teal colored rectangle
c.fillStyle = '#ccc'
c.fillRect(0, 0, 100, 100)
//make a pink rectangle
c.fillStyle = '#fff'
c.fillRect(100, 100, 100, 100)
//create rectangle object
function Rectangle(x, y, width, height, color) {
  this.x = x
  this.y = y
  this.width = width
  this.height = height
  this.color = color
  this.draw = function() {
    c.fillStyle = this.color
    c.fillRect(this.x, this.y, this.width, this.height)
  }
}
// Make grey rectangles at 200 px intervals
for (let i = 0; i < canvas.width; i += 200) {
  for (let j = 0; j < canvas.height; j += 200) {
    let rectangle = new Rectangle(i, j, 100, 100, 'rgba(128,128,128,1.0)')
    rectangle.draw()
  }
}
// Make grey rectangles at 200 px intervals
for (let i = 100; i < canvas.width; i += 200) {
  for (let j = 100; j < canvas.height; j += 200) {
    let rectangle = new Rectangle(i, j, 100, 100, 'rgba(128,128,128,1)')
    rectangle.draw()
  }
}
```

```html
<canvas></canvas>
```

Comment: A simple observation if I may. You're filling every single square of that board. Hmmmm. There's only 2 colours, so you need to do ((nSquares/2) + 1) fills. First, fill the whole board with either colour, next, fill every second square. I.e - one of your loops can be replaced with a single `fillRect` call. ;)

Comment: I've edited your question with the hope of improving it. Please check it for me and either roll it back to one of your earlier versions if I've added no help at all. or edit the current version in order that it better addresses your needs.

Comment: Thanks  for the edit, it helped make the question clearer

Comment: @enhzflep, yeah can you post your code that would achieve the checker-board circular objects for me

Comment: @CodeTiger - No. But I'd be more than happy to help you fix your own non-working attempt. It's an easy task and you're already stuck for an unknown reason. What stopped you from drawing the checkers yourself? You don't need the answer anywhere near as much as you need the knowledge of how to go about finding/computing answers.

Comment: Never mind, someone else did, thanks for the concern anyways

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like your previous question, a good answer depends on a good representation.  If you're building a real game, the game code will want to state which square to draw which piece, something like this.

```js
const canvas = document.querySelector('canvas')
const c = canvas.getContext('2d')
//make a teal colored rectangle
c.fillStyle = '#ccc'
c.fillRect(0, 0, 100, 100)
//make a pink rectangle
c.fillStyle = '#fff'
c.fillRect(100, 100, 100, 100)
//create rectangle object
function Rectangle(x, y, width, height, color) {
  this.x = x
  this.y = y
  this.width = width
  this.height = height
  this.color = color
  this.draw = function() {
    c.fillStyle = this.color
    c.fillRect(this.x, this.y, this.width, this.height)
  }
}

 const squarePx = 100
 // const cols = 4, rows = Math.ceil(canvas.height / squarePx)
 const cols = 8, rows = 8
 for (let col = 0; col < cols; col++) {
   for (let row = 0; row < rows; row++) {
     let x = col * squarePx, y = row * squarePx
     // on even rows, even cols are dark. on odd rows, odd cols are dark
     let evenRow = row % 2 === 0, evenCol = col % 2 === 0
     let fillStyle = evenRow === evenCol ? '#222' : '#888' 
     // draw at x, y, using fillStyle
     let rectangle = new Rectangle(x, y, squarePx, squarePx, fillStyle)
     rectangle.draw()
   }
 }
 
 function drawChecker(row, col, color) {
   c.fillStyle = color;
   c.beginPath();
   c.arc((col*squarePx)+50, (row*squarePx)+50, 25, 25, 0, 2*Math.PI);
   c.fill();
}
 
 // draw some checkers in initial positions

 for (let row = 0; row<2; row++) {
  for (let col = 0; col<8; col++) {
    let evenRow = row % 2 === 0, evenCol = col % 2 === 0
    if (evenRow !== evenCol) drawChecker(row, col, 'red')
  }
}

 for (let row = 6; row<8; row++) {
  for (let col = 0; col<8; col++) {
    let evenRow = row % 2 === 0, evenCol = col % 2 === 0
    if (evenRow === evenCol) drawChecker(row, col, 'white')
  }
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head></head>
<body>
  <canvas width='800' height='800'></canvas>
</body>
```

Comment: Remarkable, can you just edit it one final time to make it skip a box after drawing on the initial one please?

Comment: draw on alternating boxes on the first three columns, please my friend. I need you

Comment: @CodeTiger - I don't understand. Can you state in terms of color, row, and col where you want something drawn?  Like this: "Please draw a red checker in row 0, col 1.  Please draw a white checker in row 1, col 0 ".

Comment: please draw a red checker on `row 0, column2`, please draw a red checker on `row 0, column4`, please draw a red checker on `row 0, column 6`, please draw a checker on `row 0, column 8`

Comment: @CodeTiger - You just wrote the code! You just said `drawChecker(0, 2, 'red'); drawChecker(0, 4, 'red');` and so on! (I apologize for lying. I did understand your question :-))

Comment: please draw a red checker on `row 1, column 1`, please draw a red checker on `row 1, column 3`, please draw a red checker on `row 1, column 5`, please draw a red checker on `row 1, column7`

Comment: No problem ,Thanks for trying to answer me man..So will you edit the answer to make it draw like that?

Comment: Thanks brother, God bless. Your code worked.. Just typed drawchecker() and passed the arguments and it worked

Comment: @danh - That Dan, was a piece of mastery. Precisely the guided learning I'd clumsily been hoping to offer. "Catch yer own fish, it's easy. I'll help ya. You'll be fine"